# SQL very tricky procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, procedure

I am a bit obsessed now with this quiz, it seems I cant find a way out... hehe .

Let's see - we have two tables:

- **actor** (`id, salary, bonus`)
- **info** (`id, name, surname`)

The question is, to create a procedure so that it shows `salary, bonus, name, surname` of the actor and additionally his final paycheck = (`bonus + salary`) .

To begin with I tried this: (just to show the `salary, bonus, name, surname` and not the total paycheck, but it failed big time).

```
create or replace procedure show_things AS
BEGIN 
   Select a.id, a.salary, a.bonus 
   From actor a
   where  a.id in 
               (select i_id, i.name, i.surname 
                from info i 
                where i_id = a_id);
END;
```

I mean, is it possible to show things using a procedure ? I really can't understand this question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any `<br>` tags and such messy stuff, either!

Comment: Thanks for the info mate. It was really messy, indeed.

Comment: Hmm not really, its not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know which version of SQL that you're using, but essentially, you're going to want to join two tables and query from them, like so:

```
SELECT
     actor.salary,
     actor.bonus,
     info.name,
     info.surname,
     actor.salary + actor.bonus AS total_pay
FROM actor INNER JOIN info;
```

Done :-)

Comment: `JOIN` needs an `ON` clause.

Comment: Or it needs a comma instead of `INNER JOIN` with a proper where clause like `WHERE actor.id = info.id`.

Comment: Whoops. I'll turn it into a community wiki and you guys can edit it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple join:

```
SELECT
     a.id,
     a.salary,
     a.bonus,
     i.name,
     i.surname,
     a.salary + a.bonus AS final_paycheck
FROM 
     actor a INNER JOIN info i
ON 
     a.id= i.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure won't compile as-is. You'll (at least) need to define some local variables, and use the `INTO` clause to select into them.

You can then output the result of your procedure using `dbms_output.put_line()`, assuming that you have `SERVEROUTPUT` turned on.

In addition, you can't use the `IN` operator with a different number of columns (1) to that in the subquery it references (3). You should use a simple `JOIN` as others have suggested.

Please see the sample in the [PL/SQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#BABHFEHA).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipepline function to achieve this.

```
--    drop type t_actor_tab;
--    drop type t_actor_obj;
--    drop function get_actor_ptf;
--    drop table ACTOR;
--    drop table info;

CREATE TABLE ACTOR(ID NUMBER, SAL NUMBER, BONUS NUMBER);
INSERT INTO ACTOR(ID, SAL, BONUS) VALUES(1, 1200, 120);
INSERT INTO ACTOR(ID, SAL, BONUS) VALUES(2, 1300, 240);
INSERT INTO ACTOR(ID, SAL, BONUS) VALUES(3, 1500, 120);

CREATE TABLE INFO(ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(30), SURNAME VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO INFO(ID, NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(1, 'ABC', 'abc');
INSERT INTO INFO(ID, NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(2, 'xyz', 'xyz');
INSERT INTO INFO(ID, NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(3, 'MNO', 'mno');


CREATE TYPE t_actor_obj AS OBJECT (
      id           NUMBER
     ,sal       NUMBER
     ,bonus        NUMBER
     ,final_paycheck NUMBER
    );  

CREATE TYPE t_actor_tab IS TABLE OF t_actor_obj;



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_actor_ptf 
    RETURN t_actor_tab PIPELINED AS

    CURSOR get_details_cur
    IS 
     SELECT a.id
           ,a.sal
           ,a.bonus
           ,(a.sal+a.bonus) final_paycheck
    From actor a
    where  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM info i WHERE i.id = a.id);

   v_details_row  get_details_cur%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
      OPEN get_details_cur;
      LOOP
        FETCH get_details_cur INTO v_details_row;
        EXIT WHEN get_details_cur%NOTFOUND;
           PIPE ROW(t_actor_obj (v_details_row.id,v_details_row.sal,v_details_row.bonus,v_details_row.final_paycheck));   
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE get_details_cur;

      RETURN;
    END;
    /

 SELECT * FROM   TABLE(get_actor_ptf);

        ID        SAL      BONUS FINAL_PAYCHECK
 ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
     1       1200        120           1320 
     2       1300        240           1540 
     3       1500        120           1620
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE ACTOR(ID BIGINT, SAL BIGINT, BONUS BIGINT);
INSERT INTO ACTOR(ID, SAL, BONUS) VALUES(1, 1200, 120), (2, 1300, 240),(3, 1500, 120);

CREATE TABLE INFO(ID BIGINT, NAME VARCHAR(30), SURNAME VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO INFO(ID, NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(1, 'ABC', 'abc'), (2, 'xyz', 'xyz'), (3, 'MNO', 'mno')

SELECT * FROM ACTOR
SELECT * FROM INFO

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1()
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN

DECLARE DISPLAY CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SELECT X.ID, Y.NAME, Y.SURNAME, X.SAL, X.BONUS, X.SAL + X. BONUS AS TOTAL FROM ACTOR X JOIN INFO Y ON X.ID = Y. ID ;
OPEN DISPLAY;

END@
```

**CALL SP1()**